# How to properly make a GET call in React returning an observable (resembling the method in Angular and not using promises)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs, observable

In Angular, I usually subscribe to a client providing me with an observable of a GET call [as Google dictates](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data).

```
httpClient.get<Data>("http://blah")
  .subscribe(
    result => { ... },
    error => { ... },
    () => { ... }
  );
```

I'm trying to learn React and perform corresponding operation. The info I find is about using promises, which I prefer not to go with. Of course, the services of Angular lack their counterpart in React as such but since *rxjs* is an independent library, I feel that it makes sense to try to incorporate it into a React project.

How do I do that and what am I missing in my googling looking for it?

I'm also humbly considering the alternative that, since React is based on a different paradigm (i.e. stores instead of services), I might be barking up a very awkward tree.

Comment: Do you have some specific motivation to not use promises? There are not so many cases where you can really benefit from using Http observable in Angular (basically the cases are piping, cancellation and retry). I find myself doing toPromise() in 90% cases because it plays nicely with `async..await`. In React, there are much less benefits, unless you're already heavily using observables throughout the app.

Comment: @estus I'll be emitting data over an extended period of time shooting in values as they become available.

Comment: The reason why there's not much information about how RxJS is used with React is that React doesn't have observables that could be used as sources. So the thing you're doing isn't framework specific. You can use promises with `mergeMap` as well, btw. Extracting `Http` from Angular and using it in React would be not a bad idea as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just instead of Angular's `httpClient` you can use build-in RxJS ajax methods:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

ajax.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-nsgdri?file=index.ts

Answer (score 4):

The reason why Angular `Http` benefits from observables is that some parts of Angular use observables, so they can be efficiently composed, e.g. reactive form observable can be throttled and piped to `Http`. It's not uncommon that `Http` observable is converted `toPromise()`, just because it's complete observable with single value and it can benefit from `async..await` when being a promise.

Unless React project heavily uses observables (for instance, with `redux-observable`), there will be much less benefits than in Angular.

As another answer mentions, there's built-in HTTP request API in RxJS, `rxjs/ajax`. It's a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`, this means that it provides cancellable requests, as opposed to some promise-based APIs, notably Fetch. It's very simplistic and lacks features that may be expected from `Http` alternative - interceptors, etc.

Axios can be generally recommended as framework-agnostic, full-featured promise-based alternative to Angular `Http`. It was modeled after AngularJS `$http`. A promise from it can be converted to an observable but additional measures should be taken to make a request cancellable.

TL;DR: the biggest selling of `Http` is that its observables can be composed with other observables. If there are none, the benefits are much less obvious. Promises can benefit from `async..await` syntactic sugar while observables have to be converted to promises any way to benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on a next example:

This works when you want to cancel AJAX request on a component destroy or debounce AJAX on the input values are changed.

Solution is provided using React Hooks and RxJS:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ajax } from "rxjs/ajax";
import { debounceTime, delay, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/internal/Subject";

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [filterChangedSubject] = useState(() => {
    // Arrow function is used to init Singleton Subject. (in a scope of a current component)
    return new Subject<string>();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Effect that will be initialized once on a react component init.
    const subscription = filterChangedSubject
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe((filter) => {
        if (!filter) {
          setLoading(false);
          setItems([]);
          return;
        }
        ajax(`https://swapi.dev/api/people?search=${filter}`)
          .pipe(
            // current running ajax is canceled on filter change.
            takeUntil(filterChangedSubject)
          )
          .subscribe(
            (results) => {
              // Set items will cause render:
              setItems(results.response.results);
            },
            () => {
              setLoading(false);
            },
            () => {
              setLoading(false);
            }
          );
      });

    return () => {
      // On Component destroy. notify takeUntil to unsubscribe from current running ajax request
      filterChangedSubject.next("");
      // unsubscribe filter change listener
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const onFilterChange = (e) => {
    // Notify subject about the filter change
    filterChangedSubject.next(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Cards
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      <input onChange={onFilterChange}></input>
      {items && items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

NOTE: Use switchMap to start AJAX call. In this case you will subscribe once and have the same results.

Comment: i dont like subscribe in subscribe personally

Comment: @Paulquappe you are right, this code part can be reimplemented as one flow with only one subscribe.